# Refresh asp.net page from a code-behind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-refresh

I have an ASP.NET website and a seperate C# application. The application writes data to a file, the website populates the treeview with the data in the file. I populate the treeview in the page Load event.

The website checks if the file has changed. This happens from a code behind file. If the file did change, the website needs to be refreshed. I cannot use `Response.Redirect` because I get a

> Response is not available in this context

I tried `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect`, but this gives me a NullReference.

How can I refresh the page from a code behind file, so that it loads the right data in the treeview? Other suggestions that work but use something else than refreshing the page are welcome. Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** The actual problem is dynamically updating the treeview (new data = updated treeview). I have tried to do something with data from a MySql database but failed. The idea is the same, except the data isn't coming from a file but from a database. I added this because I thought this info might help users understand my problem.

Comment: Are you trying to do the redirect from your C# application?

Comment: No, from the code behind file from the asp.net page.

Comment: What is the context? Where, within the lifecycle of the page, is this being attempted?

Comment: And Response is not available? That's odd. Where in your code-behind specifically are you calling it?

Comment: In the Load page event I use a FileSystemWatcher to check if a file has been changed. In the Changed event I try to refresh it. I've edited my post with some additional info about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't send data to the client from an initiative of the server.

You will have to poll (jQuery/ajax) if new data is available, then refresh from the client side.

this involves basically :

- on the server

  - a web service, webmethod page method, custom handler, etc. that can tell if new data is available
- on the client

  - a timer that query the server if data is refreshed, and, in this case, that refresh the page, or reconstruct the DOM if using some JS templating

[Edit] a bit of background :

Actually, `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response` is null because of the asynchronous model of the Http protocol. The browser emits a request "http://srv/resource", the server intercept it on the port 80 (by default), parse the request, build a response (mostlya bunch of html content) and send the response the browser. Then the connection is closed. This choice allows a great scalability, as it does not requires to keeps thousands of connections alive with nearly no data passing on it.

The impact of this, is that the web server have to knowledge of the client, other than what is send in the request. The server receive text, and send text in return.

Microsoft has created the ASP.Net framework to reproduce the RAD feeling of desktop applications. You think with controls and events, not in producing html flow like ASP or PHP. They succeeded in the sense, that, building web apps are ***quite*** similar to desktop development.

The ***quite*** is actually what is causing you some confusion. Even if the asp.net framework encapsulate most of the plumbing (viewstate is the key) to simulate this behavior, asp.net will, at least, still be a parser for request text that produces a html text to send to the client, in one shot.

So you have to cheat. You can, as I suggested, automate the browser (using javascript) to wrap this asynchronous work into a "dynamic" application.

Comment: What do you mean by client side? The webpage (Default.aspx) instead of the code-behind file (Default.aspx.cs)? I'm calling the Redirect function from the asp.net application, not my server application. Btw, I've added some additional info about the problem in my post.

Comment: He means the CLIENT side. Default.aspx = SERVER SIDE. The generated HTML is sent to the browser = CLient. So you need to emit code (Javascript) into the html page that polls regularly.

Comment: I think that Web Forms is a beautiful web framework but it is absolutely disasterous way to learn about the web. @Carlito please go learn how the web works.

Comment: @stilgar: it's the MS way strategy, give the possibility to a majority of developers to build apps quickly. Let power developers hack the inner Render method of controls :p..... or wait few years for the release of asp.net mvc (far more powerfull, but requires a wider range of skills)

Comment: I think the development strategy is fine but the educational strategy kind of failed. I don't really like ASP.NET MVC (compared to Web Forms) because to me being a power developer does not mean that you should code with a lower level of abstraction all the time.

Comment: you are right... there is place for both framework, with pro/cons for each side.

Answer (score 0):

You can't successfully use a FileSystemWatcher from within a webpage.

The instance of the page lives just long enough to handle a single request. And after that request has been served, you can't issue a redirect. The browser will not be listening anymore.

You need to do polling from your webpage, using the date you last read that file. If the Last Modified date of that file has changed from what you remember, you will need to refresh your page.